# error CS0122 in VS public sealed class ArrayBufferWriter<T>

Tags: class, public, sealed

i want to use

```cs
public sealed class ArrayBufferWriter<T> : System.Buffers.IBufferWriter<T>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraybufferwriter-1?view=net-5.0

Compiler in VisualStudio gives me error CS0122

> CS0122 Access to "ArrayBufferWriter " is not possible due to the degree of protection.

```cs
var outputBuffer = new ArrayBufferWriter< byte >();
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this error?

Comment: For me the affected framework was .NET Standard 2.0 so I simply wrapped the code in `#if !NETSTANDARD2_0 #else #endif` and made another implementation for .NET Standard specifically.